# Is there any difference between heat and entropy here?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Wng.jpg) is from the Carnot Cycle page on Wikipedia. In the "Stages" section, it says that:

> The gas expansion is propelled by absorption of heat energy, $Q_1$, and of entropy, $\Delta S=Q_1/T_1$ from the high temperature reservoir.

Why do they mention the second part about the entropy? They speak of it as though it is a second, **distinct** cause of the gas's expansion. It seems redundant to mention the entropy because during this *isothermal* stage, heat is increasing, yes, but that's already mentioned by "propelled by absoption of heat energy". Is it accurate the way it's written or nah?

Comment: Maybe there is intricacy in the language; but the fact is true; gas expansion _causes_ the entropy to increase and not the vice-versa. But still, you can _correlate_ the entropy increase with the expansion. That's it. And ultimately it all boils down to the calculation and it doesn't matter what language has been used till the equations are correct.

Comment: @user36790 that's what I was thinking too. It was just worded so strangely.

Comment: yep! It's just word play and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

it's $dS = \frac{dQ}{T} $

It's the change/flow of heat in the system(s), not just the heat. This is where you confusion lies, as the Carnot Cycle is a *perfect* engine.